# Filtering a list <li> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to filter a list (show/hide the lis) based on the contents of a span within the li. Currently I have something working, but it filters the list no matter where the match occurs. I need it to be seeded to the start, so only if the match occurs at the start of the span will it be shown, otherwise it will be hidden.

```
<li><img/><span>text</span></li>
<li><img/><span>other text</span></li>
<li><img/><span>other words</span></li>
```

so, if I filter on "text", currently the first 2 would be returned whereas I only want the first (as the word "text" is at the start of it).

This is what I currently have:

```
var value = $("#listcontainer ul#list input").val();
if(value == '') {
    $('ul#list> li').show(); //show all, if nothing entered
} else {
    $('ul#list > li:not(.plain):not(:contains(' + value + '))').hide(); 
$('ul#list > li:not(.plain):contains(' + value + ')').show();
} //.plain = li which contains the text input
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('ul#list > li:not(.plain)').text(function(i, text) {
   var show = text.slice(0, value.length) === value;//starts with value
   $(this).toggle(show);//if starts with val show otherwise hide
});
```

This will check if the text of each li starts with the value and show it if it does, otherwise hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var value = $("#listcontainer ul#list input").val().toLowerCase();
if (value == '') {
    $('ul#list> li').show(); //show all, if nothing entered
} else {
    var $lis = $('ul#list > li:not(.plain)').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase().indexOf(value) == 0;
    });
    $('ul#list > li:not(.plain)').not($lis).hide();
    $lis.show();
} //.plain = li which contains the text input
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I went with megawac answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you got this to work, you would run into all sorts of problems trying to escape parentheses, etc.

Try the more readable

```
var value = $("#listcontainer ul#list input").val();
if(value == '') {
    $('ul#list> li').show();
} else {
    $('ul#list > li').each(function() {
        if($(this).text() == value) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Also, know that `filter` is an option (though for your problem, I would go with the solution above).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I went with megawac answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
var value = $("#listcontainer ul#list input").val();
if(value == '') {
    $('ul#list> li').show(); //show all, if nothing entered
} else {
    $('ul#list > li').each(function() { $(this).toggle(
                                          $(this).find('span').text() == value); });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I went with megawac answer above.